# Solr facets ignore stopwords at query time

Tags: solr, facet, stop-words

I am using Solr 4.6.0 and I am trying to get the most frequent terms grouped by year. Since it is possible that my stopwords can change often, I do not apply the stopwords at *indexing* time. Instead, all dynamic word-lists like stopwords, protwords and synonyms are  used at *query* time. But although the stopword-list includes terms like "of" and "the", they are still displayed in the result-list (see *Results*).

**Question**: How can I get facetted and stopword-filtered results, if I use the *StopFilterFactory* only at query time?

**Additional information**

If I use the *StopFilterFactory* at *indexing* time, everything is as expected. The terms like "of" and "the" are filtered out, when I run my query.

I also have tested the functionality of the *fieldtype* text_en with the Solr admin analysis tool and the results are as expected - "of" and "the" are filtered out. That means that somehow the *SearchHandler* does not call the right *analyzer*?

**Query**

`http://ip:port/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.pivot=year,text`

**Results**

```
[..]
<lst name="facet_pivot">
  <arr name="year,text">
    <lst>
      <str name="field">year</str>
      <int name="value">2009</int>
      <int name="count">139</int>
      <arr name="pivot">
        <lst>
          <str name="field">text</str>
          <str name="value">of</str>
          <int name="count">135</int>
        </lst>
        <lst>
          <str name="field">text</str>
          <str name="value">the</str>
          <int name="count">135</int>
        </lst>
        <lst>
          <str name="field">text</str>
          <str name="value">and</str>
          <int name="count">123</int>
[..]
```

**Schema.xml**

```
<field name="year" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    [..]
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
          <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Comment: Could you expound a little on why your stop words change frequently? I'm wondering if a different approach is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not because of your query?

```
http://ip:port/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.pivot=year,text
```

From what I can see, you're searching for everything, so it means it will return the stopwords also. I mean, if the query is getting passed to the analyzer, the filter class of the analyzer only see

```
*:*
```

as the query, so I don't think it will remove anything from the query string that way.

If you really want to search for everything, but without any stopwords, you can try to either search with the [negative query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax). Of course, if you use this, you will need to have a different configuration which doesn't filter any stopwords for the query, then you can put the stopwords manually as negative query to filter them out. So you're basically searching for anything, but leaving out the result which contains the negative query.

But one easy way (and better way according to my opinion) to get what you want is actually to use the copy field in the field configuration. But this will increase your index size. So what we do here with our solr is, aside from the normal field, we have other language fields like text_en, text_de, text_es etc. And we have a language detector which can detect the language, copy the field to the appropriate language, and run the correct stopwords filter.

You can also do this if you want, in your schema.xml, just create a new field, text_en_filtered, and copy the text from text_en there, and filter the stopwords there. Then you can just search in that field which doesn't have any stopwords anymore.

```
<field name="text_en_filtered" type="text_en_filtered" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
<copyField source="text" dest="text_en_filtered"/>
<fieldType name="text_en_filtered" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    ... // Analyzer with stopwords filtering here..
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the thread - [does solr support query time only stopwords?](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/does-solr-support-query-time-only-stopwords-td4069087.html) from Solr Mailing List.

This sounds very similar to your requirements and their workaround was to enable the stopFilterFactory at index time, however without a stopwords file specified to get it working as expected.

Comment: "while querying on stopwords returned 0 match" IMHO the solution does not apply in this case since the StopFilter is applied on the query itself thus why 0 matches, (which is not the case of faceting..)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question is not clear. 
So i am guessing and attempting to answer what might be your question. 
Here is how stopwords processed. If you have `<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />` during index time, Solr will not index stop words and you will not see these words in your resulting facets. Also, you need to use this during query time for proper matches.

If you have `<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />` during query time you are only removing the stopwords from your query phrase before Solr executes your query.

**Update** Your incorrect understanding of analysis chain seem to be cause of your confusion. Your q paramter is "*:*" , So if you have StopFilterFactory during query time, as mentioned above you  will filter stopwords words from "*:*" not from query results. You will endup with still stopdwords in your results since you are facetting on text. You need to understand that query time analysis is on QUERY not on results.Your "text" still got stopwords which will show up in results. It is better and easy to remove results that you do not want on client side in this case.

Comment: I've just edited my question. I hope that everything is clear now. I also tried to understand your answer, but I am not completely clear.

Comment: Ok, move Stoppard filter from query to index and re index .

Comment: As I pointed out, it is essential for me to remove the stopwords at query time. If I applyed the stopwords-filter at index time, I would have to re-index everytime I change the stopwords-list. And that does not fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you will have to reindex, unless you can dig into the faceting code and filter them out before aggregation process. 
You can speed up the process by reducing the document set to reindex only to the documents that contains the new stop word/s in case.